# ActiveRecord Query (Castle, Performance)

Tags: database, nhibernate, pagination, castle-activerecord

I've 3 tables:

- **Parts**: `Name`: internal name, `Active`: bool
- **Languages**: list of languages (English, French, German, ....)
- **PartsTranslations**: `RealName` and Id's of the other 2 tables.

I would like to get a list of **Parts** telling me the internal `name`, `active` status **and** how many translations are missing (total lang subtract translations made)

I made this SQL query that is giving me what I need (I don't know if this is the better way to make it or not, but it's working):

```
SELECT 
    parts1.name, 
    parts1.active, 
    (
        (SELECT count(lang.id) 
            FROM languages AS lang) 
        - 
        (SELECT count(trans.id)
            FROM parts AS parts2 
            INNER JOIN partstranslations as trans
            ON parts2.id = trans.partid
            WHERE parts2.id = parts1.id)        
    )
from parts as parts1;
```

**1º question-** How can I make this query using Castle ActiveRecord?

**2º question-** How's the performance of the final query (expensive one)?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Linq with Castle ActiveRecord if that is a useful option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this query in ActiveRecord using `HqlBasedQuery`, so I post here the answer to help others in the same situation as me.

```
HqlBasedQuery query = new HqlBasedQuery(typeof(Part),
 @"
    SELECT                     
        par.Id, 
        par.Name, 
        par.Active,                                         
        (SELECT count(*) - count(trans) FROM Language)                                                            
    FROM Part par
        LEFT JOIN par.PartsTranslations trans
    GROUP BY par.Id, par.Name, par.Active, trans.Part
    ");
query.SetQueryRange(startId, currentPageSize);

var results = from object[] summary in
              (ArrayList)ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(query)
          select new PartProjection
          {
              Id = (int)summary[0],
              Name = (string)summary[1],
              Active = (bool)summary[2],
              TransMissing = (long)summary[3]                                       
          };
```

I also have pagination made on this query and it also give me a stronged typed `PartProjection` objects. This class does NOT need to have any ActiveRecord parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I can't help with ActiveRecord, but this query should perform better than the one with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.active, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM languages) - count(pt.divid)
FROM
    Parts p
    LEFT JOIN PartsTranslations pt ON p.id=pt.divid
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.active
```

Or, if you do want to use the correlated subquery, you don't need to select from `Parts` in it again:

```
SELECT 
    p.name, 
    p.active, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM Languages) - 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM PartsTranslations WHERE divid = p.id)            
FROM Parts p;
```

Comment: Your second query is working but I can't run the first one :S   ----> Column 'p.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. How can I make it run?

Comment: Adding in: GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.active it's working :) Now just need to know how to run this in activerecord :P Thanks Lukas